# Django views.py add multiple files

Tags: python, django, file, upload

I have a model.py in which I would like to upload multiple files. In my models I have main class and another which I'm trying to use to upload multiple file as suggested. Problem is, I get the following error in my class in views.py 'Exception Value:  Unknown field(s) (file) specified for Post' and I can't get it to upload multiple files.

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Naslov predmeta")
    # a lot more field here but not important
    file_1 = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='PN_datoteke/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Datoteka 1", validators=[validate_file_size])
    file_2 = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='PN_datoteke/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Datoteka 2", validators=[validate_file_size])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class File(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='PN_datoteke/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Datoteke", validators=[validate_file_size])
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content_don', 'subject', 'rn_number', 'file_1', 'file_2']


    def form_valid(self, form):   

        form.instance.author = self.request.user

        
        #here I have a lot of code to process data which is writen in the fields

        response = super(PostCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
        #################################################################
        ##### this code below I'm trying to use to upload multiple files
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        if self.request.FILES:
            for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                obj = self.model.objects.create(file=f)


        return response
```

I also tried using forms, but I can't get my scripts/querys and simmilar to work then. Is there a way to add file from class File in models to my views.py class and then use it to upload multiple fiels? Or is there a easier way?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, File

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content_don', 'subject', 'rn_number', 'report_division', 'report_department', 'nc_type', 'number_res_people', 'res_person_1', 'res_person_2', 'res_person_3', 'res_person_4', 'urgency',
                  'date_days', 'cost_pn', 'cost_pn_tip', 'reklamacija', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']
class PostFileForm(PostForm): #extending form
    file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    class Meta(PostForm.Meta):
        fields = PostForm.Meta.fields + ['file',]
```

html template has a script to add multiple files upload option to my field, I'm not using widgets in forms.

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id_file_1').attr("multiple","true");

      })
    </script>
```

Comment: do you want to use some functions views ?  if yes i can help you because i am not so familiar with class based view.

Comment: why don't use `bulk_create` here `obj = self.model.objects.create(file=f)`